# Monte Carlo for 3 or more consecutive faces

Tags: r, statistics, montecarlo

I wrote this code to check for 3 or more consecutive faces in a simulation of 100000 iterations, with five rolls of a fair die. I think it is in the right track, but I am missing something. I keep getting a missing value error:

```
nrep = 500000
count = 0
for (i in 1:nrep) {
  roll = sample(6, 5)
  print(roll)
  if (roll[i] == roll[i+1] & roll[i+1] == roll[i+2]) count = count + 1
}
print(count)
```

Please advise on a correction using base R only.

Comment: You are indexing something of length 5 (`roll`) with a value that can be as large as `nrep`. I'm thinking of another solution (to be posted as answer in some minutes). 
EDIT: You are also usgin `sample()` by default, which has `replace=FALSE`. Thsi means you will never see consecutive faces because no numbers can be repeated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding to my comment, you can use the function `rle()` to compute the lengths and values of runs of equal values in a vector. You can do something like the following

```r
nrep = 500000
count = 0
for (i in 1:nrep) {
  roll = sample(6, 5, replace = TRUE)
  roll_rle = rle(roll)
  if (any(roll_rle$lengths >= 3)) {
    print(roll)
    count = count + 1
  }
}
```

Comment: This seems to work as I intended! Thank you, @Tomas!